# awk if loop not able to print

Tags: awk

I have a variable `Test` as below

```
Test="Environment Dev"
```

I want to compare `col2` char 1 with others and print the whole name of env

this is what i did

```
echo $Test|awk '{
if ($2 == "^D*")
print "DEV";
else
print "$2"
}'
```

I am getting `$2` as output but if its Test , comparing `D` with `T` I want output as `TEST`

I also tried this but output is not changing when `col2` changes.

```
echo $Test|awk '{
if ($2 ~ "^D*")
print "DEVELOPMENT"
else
print "$2"
}'
DEVELOPMENT
```

Please help where I am making mistake

Answer (score 2):

Some errors I see in your awk script:

- Use `~ /whatever/` for regular expressions.
- Do not add an asterisk in the `^D` regexp, that will also match zero `D` characters.
- Remove the quotes around the `$2` to avoid printing it literally.

A possible solution:

```
echo $Test | awk '{
if ($2 ~ /^D/)
  print "DEV";
else
  print $2
}'
```

Comment: awesome looks like this works.

Comment: Roaima -  I am not sure how to mark this post as ANSWERED

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `bash` or `ksh` or `zsh`, you don't even need to use `awk`, you can use `${parameter#word}` to remove a prefix...in this case the prefix of "all characters up to the first space":

```
$ Test="Environment Dev"
$ SecondWord=${Test#* }
$ echo $SecondWord
Dev

$ [[ $SecondWord =~ ^D ]] && echo DEV || echo $SecondWord
DEV

$ SecondWord=Foo
$ [[ $SecondWord =~ ^D ]] && echo DEV || echo $SecondWord 
Foo
```

This may work in some other Bourne-like shells, but I tested it only in the three I mentioned above.

BTW, if you want a "greedy" match (i.e. longest matching string rather than shortest - so that you're getting the LAST word rather than the second and subsequent, if any, words), use `##` rather than `#`.

Comment: Thanks the issue is resolved.  THanks all for the answers